# ImportError: cannot import name EXT_MSG

Tags: ros, catkin-make, genmsg, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I am using ubuntu14.04+indigo

I got an error when I run `catkin_make`

```
[ 67%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py", line 41, in <module>
    from genmsg import EXT_MSG, EXT_SRV, MsgContext
ImportError: cannot import name EXT_MSG
make[2]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionResult] Error 1
make[1]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionResult.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py", line 41, in <module>
    from genmsg import EXT_MSG, EXT_SRV, MsgContext
ImportError: cannot import name EXT_MSG
make[2]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionGoal] Error 1
make[1]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionGoal.dir/all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py", line 41, in <module>
    from genmsg import EXT_MSG, EXT_SRV, MsgContext
ImportError: cannot import name EXT_MSG
make[2]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionActionResult] Error 1
make[1]: *** [procrob_functional/CMakeFiles/_face_recognition_generate_messages_check_deps_FaceRecognitionActionResult.dir/all] Error 2
[ 67%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

please help me,thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228411/importerror:-cannot-import-name-ext_msg/) by [baogege](https://answers.ros.org/users/22605/baogege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-07**:
Please post your CMakeLists.txt
You could also try the [catkin_lint tool](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint). It's a great tool to resolve errors in your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I git clone the package named genmsg，then the error disapeared.Thank you for your advice.

---

Originally posted by [baogege](https://answers.ros.org/users/22605/baogege/) with karma: 41 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-10**:
I converted your comment to an answer. Please mark it as correct.